# Django: Problem with Getting The Right Objects

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner learning Django through a building an app, called PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models and their reviews.

Right now, I am facing a problem. I have added two phone brands, Samsung and Apple, through Django admin. They are being displayed at http://127.0.0.1:8000/index.

[image]

When I click on Samsung, I see three phone models, Galaxy S10, Galaxy Note 10 and iPhone 11, which have already been added through Django admin. However, iPhone 11 is not supposed to be displayed here, as its brand is Apple, not Samsung. So, basically, when I click on Samsung, only Galaxy S10 and Galaxy Note 10 are supposed to be displayed, not iPhone 11. 
[image]
How can I fix the issue?

Here are my codes of **models.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are my codes of **urls.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<int:pk>/', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<int:pk>/', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are my codes of **views.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_model_name'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return PhoneModel.objects.all()

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are my codes of **apps.py** located inside PhoneReview folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are my codes of **index.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'modellist' brand.id %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **phonemodel.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for phonemodel in all_model_name %}
            <li><a href = "{% url 'details' phonemodel.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **details.html** located inside templates folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/style.css" %}">


<html lang="en">

{% block title%}Details{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the Details Page</h1>

<h2>Review:</h2>
<p>{{ review.review_article }}</p>

<h2>News Link:</h2>
<p>{{ review.link }}</p>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Have I done anything wrong in **views.py**?

Comment: You return `PhoneModel.objects.all()` in your `ModelView`, which literally means "all phones".

Comment: Yes. But how can I fix the issue? I am a beginner. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your list view see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

```
class ModelView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_model_name'

   def get_queryset(self):
        self.brand = get_object_or_404(Brand, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return PhoneModel.objects.filter(brand=self.brand)
```

Comment: See this [section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)